# HTML image onmouseover event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, image, onmouseover

I have an image that's being displayed on an HTML5 canvas, to which I have added an `onmouseover` event that theoretically should call a JavaScript function that has been written in the same file.

However, when I view my page, and hover the cursor over the image, nothing happens.

I've added the image to a hidden section of my HTML using the line:

```
<img id="assetBox" src = "images/box.png" alt="Assets" onmouseover = "displayAssetDescriptionTip()"/>
```

The image has then been drawn to the canvas using the function:

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes(){
var assetsDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("assetBox");
var liabilitiesDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("liabilitiesBox");
var incomeDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("incomeBox");
var expenditureDescriptionBox = document.getElementById("expenditureBox");
assetsDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';
liabilitiesDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';
incomeDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';
expenditureDescriptionBox.src = 'images/box.png';

context.drawImage(assetsDescriptionBox, 70, 400, 120, 70);
context.drawImage(liabilitiesDescriptionBox, 300, 400, 120, 70);
context.drawImage(incomeDescriptionBox, 530, 400, 120, 70);
context.drawImage(expenditureDescriptionBox, 760, 400, 120, 70);

context.strokeText("Assets", 100, 490);
context.strokeText("Liabilities", 325, 490);
context.strokeText("Income", 550, 490);
context.strokeText("Expenditure", 775, 490);


}
```

and the function that I want to be called when the cursor is detected as hovering over the image is:

```
function displayAssetDescriptionTip(){
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Assets are items that can be bought or sold for cash.";
        console.log("displayAssetDescriptionTip being called");
}
```

But, for some reason, when I view my page in the browser, and hover the cursor over the image on the canvas, nothing happens, and nothing is displayed in the console... I assume that this means that my `onmouseover` event isn't firing, but I have no idea why this is- can anyone explain it to me, and point out what I need to do to get it right?

**Edit 22/02/2013 @ 14:40**

I tried adding the following JS to keep track of the mouse coordinates in one of the separate JS files I have:

```
/*Add code to keep track of the mouse coordinates */
var boundingBox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mousex = (mouse_event.clientX-boundingBox.left)*(canvas.width/boundingBox.width);
var mouseY = (mouse_event.clientY-boundingBox.top)*(canvas.height/boundingBox.height);
```

I know I will have to write the code to tell the script what to actually do with the coordinates, but I just wanted to give this a try first, since it's been a while since I've done any work with coordinates myself. But when I view the page in a browser, I'm getting a console error that says that "canvas is not defined, and complains about the line:

```
var boundingBox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```

I'm wondering if this is because this is a separate script file, and doesn't actually have any reference to the canvas I'm using until where I've just added it. Do I need to define it again, even though it's already been defined in the HTML page that this script is being run on?

Comment: If you look, everyone here answered the question correctly. You have to step back now and try to understand it. Sometimes getting up and doing something else, then coming back allows this as all of us get stuck in a mindset for a bit and doing something else allows us to escape it.

Comment: Just a tip on future questions you have. You had asked a lot from people and they have responded. You did not check an answer or up vote or down vote anyone. You should participate in that aspect to respect the help you received, whether it be negative or positive feedback.

Comment: Hey there, I'm very grateful for everyone's responses, and have tried out their suggestions. However, none of the answers suggested have actually solved the problem I'm having- hence why I've not 'accepted' them, but commented on the answers to clarify things further, in the hope that I might be able to work out a solution.

Comment: Right but here's the thing. The real problem you are having is not understanding how to manipulate an image when its drawn on the canvas in terms of attaching events. If you look yourself at how to do this via a library that simplifies it like raphael.js you will actually solve it.

Comment: I'm already using the KineticJS library with my canvas- to make some of the images draggable, although not the ones I want to attach an onmouseover event to- but I guess using both libraries wouldn't have a negative effect on the performance of the game?

Answer (score 0):

Just drawing an image doesn't magically make the image behave like a node. For instance, you can't change its `src` and have it automatically change the image shown on the canvas.

Instead, you have to manually track mouse movement with `onmousemove` on the canvas, then compute what the mouse is hovering over and do something about it. Having had experience making menus in Game Maker, I can tell you it's hard as hell!

Comment: I'm not trying to change the `src` of the image, just detect when the cursor is hovering over the image, and call a function when that detection occurs. The function that I'm calling changes the text displayed in a `<p></p>` tag within the `<body></body>`  of the HTML. I know that this function does work, since I am calling it when a click is detected on other images displayed on the canvas. The reason that I want to change it slightly for these images, so that rather than having to click on the image to display text, you just have to hover, is because the other images are 'draggable',

Comment: I never said you were trying to change the `src`, I just said that as an example of the difference between an `<img>` element and an image drawn on a canvas.

Comment: Ok, sorry. So would you suggest using `onmousemove` to detect to coordinates of the cursor's current location, and then if those coordinates fall inside the range of coordinates at which the image is drawn, then call the function I'm using to change the text?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption, but the image that is drawn is a different element then the one that you have the onmouseover on. Try adding a class to the image and the one being drawn and set the onmouseover on the class (check jQuery to make this process easier)

Comment: That's not the case- if you look at the code I've pasted in my question, you'll see that the image that I've given the `onmouseover` to has the ID "assetBox", and then, in my `drawDescriptionBoxes()` function, I have used a `document.getElementById()` to get the "assetBox" and assign it to the variable `assetsDescriptionBox`. I am then using the line `context.drawImage(assetsDescriptionBox, 70, 400, 120, 70);` to draw the image to the canvas, and it is the correct image that is displayed in this location.

Comment: Not get element by id, in essence you have two images with the same id which will not work. You need to assign it to a class...

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. What do you mean by assign it to a class, and how do I do that? I've not used classes before in JS.